# Is throwing inside Heuristically Unreachable Code dangerous?

Tags: c#, resharper

I've got a method that, due to some non-intuitive business requirements, requires extensive commenting.  I've had to refactor it to be less concise (defactor?), but trust me when I say that the places I've commented the following method are necessary to make sure the business requirements are not accidentally changed:

```
public bool CheckBasedOnApplicableConditions()
{
    bool conditionOne;
    bool conditionTwo;

    // Comments to explain why BusinessLogic is used
    if (BusinessLogic())
    {
        //Comments discussing SecondaryBusinessLogic
        conditionOne = true;
        conditionTwo = SecondaryBusinessLogic();
    }
    else
    {
        //Comments discussing this scenario
        conditionOne = DifferentBusinessLogic();
        conditionTwo = !conditionOne;
    }

    //Comments about the CheckForCondition calls
    if (conditionOne && CheckForConditionOne())
    {
        return true;
    }
    if (conditionTwo && CheckForConditionTwo())
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I really want to future-proof this method from being broken by a developer down the line (aka me in a month).  I feel it's important to emphasize that the business requirements include that at least one of the two conditions *must* be checked.  So I added the following code before the final return:

```
    //ReSharper normally points out this always evaluates to false,
    // but because an exception is being thrown it does not complain.
    if (!conditionOne && !conditionTwo)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException
            ("Condition One or Two must be applicable!");
    }
```

The intended effect is that if a developer carelessly violates the business requirements, the exception is thrown instead of silently returning false and creating a bug that takes time to track down.  This isn't a pattern that I've really seen much before, but ReSharper automatically suppressed its own "code is heuristically unreachable" warning when the throw was added.

**My question is**: Are there unintended side effects to this approach?  i.e., performance loss, or a maintainability issue that I'm blind to, or something else unexpected?  I am aware that I could re-factor the method to make it more stable; but I fear this will come at a cost of understanding.

Comment: Do you really care about performance when there is a must-fix defect in the code?

Comment: Everything in this question from the title to the last `.` looks like code smell to me.

Comment: @HighCore Well I won't pretend that the code is in the best shape overall.  I'm trying to make improvements but I'm limited to refactoring as I work in different areas.  I ask this question to make sure I'm taking the correct approach.

Comment: +1 for coining "defactor".

Comment: Visible error messages along the lines of "This should be impossible!!" are a recurring trope on [the daily wtf's 'Error'd' series](http://thedailywtf.com/Series/Error_0x27_d.aspx) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Self-testing code is OK up to some point, I would suggest `System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert()` here.

But verifying this kind of logic conditions is better handled by external testing, ie unit-testing or (the not yet very mature) code-contracts.

And as you can only test the results of a method this would be an argument to refactor it into smaller pieces.

Answer (score 1):

Henk's answer got me going in the right direction: I was so laser-focused on refactoring this one method it didn't occur to me that this actually needed to be two separate methods.

Now I've got:

```
public IEnumerable<Condition> DetermineConditionsToTest()
{
    //determine what conditions to return
}

public bool CheckIfAnyConditionIsMet(IEnumerable<Condition> conditionsToCheck)
{
    // check if any condition is met.
}
```

And now I have unit tests for each.  The lesson is: if you think you can't unit test something; keep breaking it down until you can.